# Azure SQL Server with Azure AD with NodeJs

Tags: sql-server, node.js, azure, active-directory

I need to query Azure SQL Server using Azure Active Directory, I have tried mssql, tediuos, odbc npm's

I'm always getting the same error:

> Cannot open the server {server} requested by the login.
>
> Login failed

How to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that the client IP is whitelisted in Azure for that SQL server, and that connection encryption is enabled?

Comment: yes marc, ip is whitelisted and encrypt=yes

Answer (score 0):

Actually, [`mssql`](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql) uses [`tedious`](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious) as TDS driver, and Azure Active Directory Authentication is currently not supported by `tedious`. The issue has been reported [here](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/issues/416).

So, you need to switch to [C# to connect Azure SQL Database with Azure AD identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure#using-an-azure-ad-identity-to-connect-from-a-client-application).

Comment: i need to achieve this in nodeJs, i found this npm edge (https://www.npmjs.com/package/edge) to use c# code in node but im not sucessful, it says assembly reference missing, if possible then suggest me ..?